# Airlines Frequency puzzle

Tags: logic, puzzle

Five airline companies P, Q, R, S and T applied to government permission to run their flights in a certain city.  The government gave them permission to have certain number of trips every year but with uniform frequency based on the fee they paid.  A regular traveler observed the trips of different flights on different days. P on 2nd July, Q on 3rd July, R on 4th July and so on.  After some days they also observed the below trips: T on July 30th, S on July 31st and R on August 1st and so on.  No flight has a trip every day.  Every flight has a trip at least once in every week.

[image]

Question 1: Frequency of which flights among P, Q, R, S can be uniquely found out ?

Question 2: Assume that each flight has a distinct frequency.  For what all flights can their frequency be definitely inferred ?

---

My thoughts on the puzzle :-

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121360/airlines-frequency-puzzle

Comment: Does the "and so on" mean there is an S flight on July 5 and a T flight on July 6 and a Q flight on August 2 and a P flight on August 3?  It seems like it should, but that is not many words to save for using "and so on".  Otherwise, what does it mean?

Comment: In the context of a puzzle, I treat "airline has uniform frequency" meaning that they fly out once every $N \leq 7$ days, as supposed to "N flights a week". $\quad$ My suggestion is that: For $R$, count the number of days from July 4th to July 31st (inclusive), and $N_R$ divides that value.

Comment: Yes @CalvinLin , you are right.   The options provided for few questions in this puzzle does have frequency as you mentioned.  In that case how should I proceed with it ?  For R I can see that the frequency cannot be 1 flight for every 2 days as then in the days 2nd and 3rd July this condition could get violated.... Can you please provide me some hints in order to think in correct direction

Comment: @CalvinLin, I am getting two frequencies for R as 1 flight in every 4 days and 1 flight in every 7 days, and it would be something of the form 4k or 7k+4  So for question 1, I can say that the frequency of R can't be uniquely identified, but then we dont have two dates for any flight except R, how can we proceed with the same method for rest of the flights ?

Comment: @VasuGupta Just because the traveler didn't observe something happen on July 3rd, doesn't mean that it didn't happen on that day.

Comment: Can the traveller observe more than 1 flight as well in a day ?

Comment: @CalvinLin why are we taking date for R from July 4 to July 31 (inclusive) , should'nt it be July 4 to August 1 (inclusive) which would give us 29 days

Comment: Yes they could, but there is no information on that. $\quad$ If the flight is every 3 days, and the first flight is on July 4th, then when is the next flight? How many days are there in between those 2 dates, taken inclusive?

Comment: It should be on July 7th and days between 4th and 7th taken inclusively will be 4 days

Comment: @CalvinLin I am getting confused on whether I can take frequency of R to be 2 or not ? because if I take it as 2 then on 2nd and 3rd July it will have to share the flights with P and Q respectively

Comment: If the flights are on July 4th, 7th, 10th, 13th, I'd say that the frequency is every 3 days, not every  4 days. Hence, the need to find the number of days between flight date and one less than flight date inclusive. $\quad$ I've not done the calculation for the number of days between July 4th to 31st. What is it? Hence, what can we say about $N_R$? $\quad$ Can you elaborate on your confusion? So what if it shares flights with other airlines? Is there a restriction that there is only 1 flight out every day?

Comment: @CalvinLin  understood that we are finding the duration between the 2 dates and then finding factors of it.  Yes there isnt any restriction given on the number of flights in a day, but if you look at my updated table, none of the flight's frequency could then be predicted and there would be no correct answer for question 1

Comment: 1/ What is the number of days for P, Q, R, S, T? 2/ What does it mean for the flight frequency to be uniquely determined? 3/ Which of the airlines satisfies that condition?

Comment: 1. I didn't get what you meant by number of  Days for P,Q,R,S,T are you asking the number of days after which the flights take place ? If yes, then I could only answer that for R that it has to be either 2, or 4 or 7 days, for rest of the flights I am unable to tell the frequeuncy.  2. Flight frequency to be uniquely determined means to me that the frequency of that particular flight always remains the same irresepective of the flight frequencies of other flights .  3) With the help of the table I have made, I am unable to conclude about it

Comment: I've posted an answer to the equivalent question on Puzzling.SE. Not sure what the correct etiquette is in this situation. Should I replicate that answer here or just post a cross-reference?

Comment: 1/ EG For R, there are 28 days between July 4th and 31st. We already discussed why this was important, so I was asking you to get that information $\quad$ 2/ What is a mathematical statement that can be made? $\quad$ 3/ Using 1+2, make the deduction.

Comment: Ohh okay, the mathematical statement I can make from R's perspective is that, the frequency of R has to be a factor of 28, so either it could have been 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28, but as per the restriction imposed by question, it would be either 2 or 4 or 7 days i.e. the flight of R takes off in every 2 days or it can take of after every 4 days and it could even take of after every 7 days, all these cases are viable .... This is my understanding ..... Also I know that each flight will have minimum frequency of 2 days and maximum frequency of 7 days.  Apart from this I can't deduce anything extra

Comment: @CalvinLin help plz

Comment: Do the same for the other airlines. That's pretty much all the you need. EG the answer to the first question is which one of them has a unique factor between 2 and 6 inclusive.